# How to overaly with an height transform css3

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a group of boxes where in the beginning has few info, and when hovering displays more info.
I achieved it but I have a problem related with the position of the other boxes. Every time I hover over one box, the others change their position because I'm applying a height and a width in hover. It work fine if I comment height and width in hover but I need to maintain de box-shadow at all time

Here you can check the test: https://jsfiddle.net/p4av5ejv/

HTML:

```
<div class="partnerLlistat">
                  <div id="partnerBox" class="partnerBox">
                    <div id="partnerData">
                        <h3>Field1: Test test</h3>
                        <h4>Field2: test</h4>
                        <p id="type">Field3: test</p>
                        <p id="address">Field4: test</p>
                        <p id="phone">Field5: 111</p>
                        <p id="web">Field6: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://test.net">http://test.net</a></p>
                        <p id="mail">Field7: test@gmail.com</p>
                        <p id="offer">Field8: test test</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div id="partnerBox" class="partnerBox">
                    <div id="partnerData">
                        <h3>Field1: Test test</h3>
                        <h4>Field2: test</h4>
                        <p id="type">Field3: test</p>
                        <p id="address">Field4: test</p>
                        <p id="phone">Field5: 111</p>
                        <p id="web">Field6: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://test.net">http://test.net</a></p>
                        <p id="mail">Field7: test@gmail.com</p>
                        <p id="offer">Field8: test test</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div id="partnerBox" class="partnerBox">
                    <div id="partnerData">
                        <h3>Field1: Test test</h3>
                        <h4>Field2: test</h4>
                        <p id="type">Field3: test</p>
                        <p id="address">Field4: test</p>
                        <p id="phone">Field5: 111</p>
                        <p id="web">Field6: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://test.net">http://test.net</a></p>
                        <p id="mail">Field7: test@gmail.com</p>
                        <p id="offer">Field8: test test</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div id="partnerBox" class="partnerBox">
                    <div id="partnerData">
                        <h3>Field1: Test test</h3>
                        <h4>Field2: test</h4>
                        <p id="type">Field3: test</p>
                        <p id="address">Field4: test</p>
                        <p id="phone">Field5: 111</p>
                        <p id="web">Field6: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://test.net">http://test.net</a></p>
                        <p id="mail">Field7: test@gmail.com</p>
                        <p id="offer">Field8: test test</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

CSS:

I cannot define CSS code because I don't know how to format well to be valid. Check in jsFiddle link.

Can anybody help me with this?, I googled a lot and stackoverflowing a lot but nothing exactly what I need.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the solution.

HTML

```
    <li id="partnerBox" class="partnerBox">
                        <h3>Nom: aaa</h3>
                        <h4 class="VisibleOnHover">Entitat: aaa</h4>
                        <p>Tipus de servei: aaa</p>
                        <div class="VisibleOnHover">
                            <p>Adreça: aaa</p>
                            <p>Telèfon: 111</p>
                            <p>Pàgina web: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://aaa.net">http://aaa.net</a></p>
                            <p>Correu electrònic: aaa@gmail.com</p>
                            <p>Avantatge que ofereix: aaa aaa</p>
                        </div>
                  </li>

                  <li id="partnerBox" class="partnerBox">
                        <h3>Nom: bbb bbb</h3>
                        <h4 class="VisibleOnHover">Entitat: bbb</h4>
                        <p>Tipus de servei: bbb</p>
                        <div class="VisibleOnHover">
                            <p>Adreça: bbb</p>
                            <p>Telèfon: 111</p>
                            <p>Pàgina web: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://bbb.net">http://bbb.net</a></p>
                            <p>Correu electrònic: bbb@gmail.com</p>
                            <p>Avantatge que ofereix: bbb bbb</p>
                        </div>
                  </li>

                  <li id="partnerBox" class="partnerBox">
                        <h3>Nom: ccc ccc</h3>
                        <h4 class="VisibleOnHover">Entitat: ccc</h4>
                        <p>Tipus de servei: ccc</p>
                        <div class="VisibleOnHover">
                            <p>Adreça: ccc</p>
                            <p>Telèfon: 111</p>
                            <p>Pàgina web: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://ccc.net">http://ccc.net</a></p>
                            <p>Correu electrònic: ccc@gmail.com</p>
                            <p>Avantatge que ofereix: ccc ccc</p>
                        </div>
                  </li>

                  <li id="partnerBox" class="partnerBox">
                        <h3>Nom: ddd ddd</h3>
                        <h4 class="VisibleOnHover">Entitat: ddd</h4>
                        <p>Tipus de servei: ddd</p>
                        <div class="VisibleOnHover">
                            <p>Adreça: ddd</p>
                            <p>Telèfon: 111</p>
                            <p>Pàgina web: <a ref="external" target="_blank" href="http://ddd.net">http://ddd.net</a></p>
                            <p>Correu electrònic: ddd@gmail.com</p>
                            <p>Avantatge que ofereix: ddd ddd</p>
                        </div>
                  </li>
              </ul>
```

Again, I don't know how to insert formatted CSS here, so check jsfiddle link to see this code.

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6p1Lzkqb/) to see how to solve that. In jsfiddle you cannot appreciate well, because you have to tune the padding and margin in the .partnerLlistat > li[id^="partnerBox"]:hover rule to your site.